# Why have a pointer to a pointer (int **a)?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int **a = malloc2d(M, N) // dynamically allocates a 2D array
```

What is the purpose of having **int **a** vice int *a.  I understand that pointers are needed for dynamic allocation but why have a pointer to a pointer?

For a 3-dimensional array would it be:

```
int ***a
```

?

Comment: Yes it would, 3 dimension arrays is where it starts to get a bit tricky, after 3 dimension arrays my head starts to hurt and i try to find another way to store my data.

Comment: A 3 dimension array is like storing information in a compartmentalized box, so if you have a 10x10x10 sized box, and each 1x1x1 stores a piece of information you can store 1000 pieces of information. But like i said after three pointer you may want to look at another way of storing the data.

An example of a 3D array use would be an image, say 1024x1024 sized bitmap, and at each of the pixels int he image you want to store an R,G,B value you could have an array of 1024x1024x3, meaning at each position on the 1024x1024 grid you can stor [0][1]and[2] peice of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a pointer to a pointer for several reasons.

In the example you gave, a double pointer is used to store the 2D array.

A 2D array in C is treated as a 1D array whose elements are 1D 
arrays (the rows).

For example, a 4x3 array of T (where "T" is some data type) may 
be declared by:  "T  mat[4][3]",  and described by the following 
scheme:

```
                       +-----+-----+-----+
  mat == mat[0]   ---> | a00 | a01 | a02 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[1]   ---> | a10 | a11 | a12 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[2]   ---> | a20 | a21 | a22 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[3]   ---> | a30 | a31 | a32 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
```

Another situation, is when you have pass a pointer to a function, and you want that function to allocate that pointer. For that, you must the address of the pointer variable, hence a pointer to a pointer

```
void make_foofoo(int** change) {
    *change = malloc(4);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In C, a pointer to type `T` points to a location where some data of type `T` is stored.  To keep things concrete, I will talk about `T = int` below.

The most simple use of a pointer could be to point to one value:

```
int a = 42;
int *pa = &a;
```

Now, `*pa` and `a` are both the same, and equal to `42`.  Also, `*pa` and `pa[0]` are both equivalent: so, for example, you can do:

```
*pa += 1; /* a is 43 */
pa[0] += 1; /* a is 44 */
a += 1; /* a is 45 */
```

In fact, the C compiler translates `pa[0]` to `*(pa+0)` automatically.

A pointer can point to a location that is inside a sequence of data:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; /* 3 ints */
int *parr = arr; /* points to 1 */
```

Now, our memory looks like this:

```
            +---+---+---+
       arr: | 1 | 2 | 3 |
            +---+---+---+
 +------+     |
 | parr | ----+
 +------+
```

`parr` is a pointer that points to the first element of `arr` in the picture above.  Incidentally, `parr` also has a box around it, because we need to store the object `parr` somewhere in the memory.  The value of `parr` is the address of the first element of `arr`.

Now, we can use `parr` to access the elements of `arr`:

```
arr[0] == parr[0]; /* true */
parr[1]++; /* make arr[1] equal to 3 */
```

So, pointer can be used to mean, "I point to the first of n elements in a contiguous store of some objects".  Of course, one has to know how many objects there are for this scheme to work: but once we remember to do so, it is an extremely convenient way to access memory in C.

Pointer can be made to point to dynamically allocated memory as well:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
size_t n;
/* now, obtain a value in n at runtime */
int *p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);
```

If the `malloc()` call succeeds above, `p` now points to the first of a contiguous area allocated for 10 `int`s.  We can use `p[0]` through `p[n-1]` in our program now.

You probably knew most or all of the above :-), but still, the above helps in understanding what I will say next.

Remember we said that a pointer can point to a contiguous sequence of objects of the same type?  The "same type" can be another pointer type as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int **pp;
pp = malloc(3 * sizeof *pp);
```

Now, `pp` points to an `int *`.  Going back to our earlier picture:

```
            +------+------+------+
            |      |      |      |
            +------+------+------+
 +------+     |
 |  pp  | ----+
 +------+
```

And each of the 3 boxes is an `int *`, which can point to the first element of a contiguous sequence of `int`s:

```
for (i=0; i < 3; ++i)
    pp[i] = malloc((i + 1) * sizeof *ppi[i]);
```

Here, we allocated space for one int in `pp[0]`, 2 in `pp[1]`, and 3 in `pp[3]`:

```
             +------+         +---+
 pp -------->|      |-------->|   |
             +------+         +---+---+
             |      |-------->|   |   |
             +------+         +---+---+---+
             |      |-------->|   |   |   |
             +------+         +---+---+---+
```

So, `pp[0]` is a pointer to one `int`, and that `int` is the only `int` in a dynamically allocated block of `int`s.  In other words, `pp[0][0]` is an `int`, and points to the top-most "width-3" box above.  Similarly, `pp[1][0]` and `pp[1][1]` are both valid and are the two boxes below the `pp[0][0]` box.

The most common use of pointer to pointer is to create a 2-dimensional "array" at runtime:

```
int **data;
size_t i;
data = malloc(n * sizeof *data);
for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
    data[i] = malloc(m * sizeof *data[i]);
```

Now, assuming that all `malloc()`s succeed, `data[0]`...`data[n-1]` are valid `int *` values, each pointing to a separate length `m` contiguous `int` objects.

But, as I showed above, a pointer to pointer need not have the same "number of elements" in each of its "rows".  The most obvious example is [`argv` in `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020945/argc-and-argv-in-main/2021328#2021328).

By now, as you can guess, a "3-level deep" pointer, such as `int ***p;` is okay and can be useful in C.

Comment: `int *pa = &42;` looks incorrect, shouldn't that be `int *pa = &a`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of fun, here's a `*****` example:

1. we have a 3d texture (a volumetric texture) -- 3 dimensions, hence `***`
2. each voxel in the texture has a color (`*`)
3. the texture is animated, has a framecount in time (`*`)

Hence we'd have tex[2][3][10][2][10].... which is:

1. Coordinate 2,3,10 in 3D
2. color 2 (green)
3. frame 10

To pass such a data with the ability to modify it, you'd need to pass a `int******`... fun! xD

(and that's why I like struct's and classes....)

Answer (score 1):

Helps to draw a picture.  Imagine a one-dimensional array, where each element contains a pointer.  Each of those pointers points to another one-dimensional array.  malloc2d isn't a standard library function, but I'm guessing its returning a two-dimensional array constructed that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to create a 2 dimension array,
kind of like a mathematical matrix, or a chessboard.
So you are able to store a table of data pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

A normal C array is a pointer to a block of memory.

A 2D array is a pointer to a list of pointers to each row of the array.

so, pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

you only ever have pass the size of a pointer (most often 32 or 64 bits) rather than entire objects.