# Notation of **argv in main function

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv, argc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [argc and argv in main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020945/argc-and-argv-in-main)

I'm having difficulty understanding the notation used for the general main function declaration, i.e. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. I understand that what is actually passed to the main function is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, but I find the notation difficult. For instance:

Why does `**argv` point to the first char and not the whole string? Likewise, why does `*argv[0]` point to the same thing as the previous example.

Why does `*argv` point to the whole first string, instead of the first `char` like the previous example?

This is a little unrelated, but why does `*argv + 1` point a string 'minus the first char' instead of pointing to the next string in the array?

Comment: argv as array of strings: `char* argv[]` `arv[0]` is the first string, `argv[0][0]` is the first byte of the first string etc.

Comment: There are no "strings" in C, just arrays of characters. Perhaps you're confused about what "pointing to the whole string" means.

Comment: You need to understand two unrelated pieces of basic C syntax: 1) in function arguments, `T[]` is the same as `T*`. 2) For a pointer `p`, `p[i]` is identical to `*(p + i)`, and also `&*p` is identical to `p`. Use that to reflect on your question.

Comment: Sounds like you're having some issues understanding pointers vs. arrays. Take a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676402/why-cant-i-treat-an-array-like-a-pointer-in-c) to see if it helps clear that up at least.

Comment: I think much of why I'm getting thrown off with this is misunderstanding regarding order of operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a program with `argc == 3`.

```
   argv
     |
     v
+---------+         +----------------+
| argv[0] |-------->| program name\0 |
+---------+         +-------------+--+
| argv[1] |-------->| argument1\0 |
+---------+         +-------------+
| argv[2] |-------->| argument2\0 |
+---------+         +-------------+
|    0    |
+---------+
```

The variable `argv` points to the start of an array of pointers.  `argv[0]` is the first pointer.  It points at the program name (or, if the system cannot determine the program name, then the string for `argv[0]` will be an empty string; `argv[0][0] == '\0'`).  `argv[1]` points to the first argument, `argv[2]` points to the second argument, and `argv[3] == 0` (equivalently `argv[argc] == 0`).

The other detail you need to know, of course, is that `array[i] == *(array + i)` for any array.

You ask specifically:

> - Why does **argv point to the first char and not the whole string?

`*argv` is equivalent to `*(argv + 0)` and hence `argv[0]`.  It is a `char *`.  When you dereference a `char *`, you get the 'first' character in the string.  And `**argv` is therefore equivalent to `*(argv[0])` or `*(argv[0] + 0)` or `argv[0][0]`.

(It can be legitimately argued that `**argv` is a character, not a pointer, so it doesn't 'point to the first char'.  It is simply another name for the `'p'` of `"program name\0"`.)

> - Likewise, why does *argv[0] point to the same thing as the previous example.

As noted before, `argv[0]` is a pointer to the string; therefore `*argv[0]` must be the first character in the string.

> - Why does `*argv` point to the whole first string, instead of the first char like the previous example?

This is a question of convention.  `*argv` points at the first character of the first string.  If you interpret it as a pointer to a string, it points to 'the whole string', in the same way that `char *pqr = "Hello world\n";` points at 'the whole string'.  If you interpret it as a pointer to a single character, it points to the first character of the string.  Think of it as like wave-particle duality, only here it is character-string duality.

> - Why does `*argv + 1` point a string 'minus the first char' instead of pointing to the next string in the array?

`*argv + 1` is `(*argv) + 1`.  As already discussed, `*argv` points at the first character of the first string.  If you add 1 to a pointer, it points at the next item; since `*argv` points at a character, `*argv+1` points to the next character.

`*(argv + 1)` points to the (first character of the) next string.

Comment: This is _very_ helpful, thank you for the response. You've helped a lot with my understanding, at least I think so. So the reason why the whole string gets printed out in say printf with `*argv` is because printf takes `char *`, so it prints out the whole string?

Comment: Yes.  If you use a `%s` format string, then `printf("%s\n", *argv);` prints the whole string.  If you use `printf("%p\n", (void *)*argv);`, then you'll get just the address printed.  (I should apologize that I'm not sure whether 'first' is used consistently; it usually means 'subscript 0'.)

Comment: Okay, thanks again for the effort put into your answer!

Answer (score 3):

It all falls down to pointer arithmetic.

```
*argv[0] = *(*(argv + 0)) = **argv
```

Since `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`.

On the other hand, `*argv` gives the first cell in the array, an array containing pointers. What does this pointer point to? Why a char array, a string, of course.

`*argv + 1` gives what it gives because `+` has lower precedence than unary `*`, so first we get a pointer to a string, and than we add 1 to it, thus getting a pointer the the second
character in the string.

Answer (score 3):

`I understand that what is actually passed to the main function is a pointer to a pointer to char`

No, what's passed is an array of char pointers (an array of character strings). Think of it like this, if I give this at the command prompt:

```
>> ./program hello 456
```

My program's main will get:

```
argc == 3

argv[0] == program (the name of the program as a string)
argv[1] == hello   (the first parameter as a string)
argv[2] == 456     (the second parameter as a string)
```

`Why does **argv point to the first char and not the whole string?`

```
char *argv[]  //an array of character pointers
*argv         // an array decays to a pointer, so this is functionally equivalent to
              // argv[0]
**argv        // Now the argv[0] decays to a pointer and this is functionally
              // equivalent to (argv[0])[0]
```

`Likewise, why does *argv[0] point to the same thing as the previous example.`

See above.

`Why does *argv point to the whole first string, instead of the first char like the previous example?`

See above.

Comment: My Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #3: "If the question starts with 'I understand', they don't."

Comment: @KerrekSB - That is a very wise rule. :)

Comment: The last example holds true, because strings are actually arrays?

Comment: @hcaulfield57 - Exactly. `argv` is an array of "strings". `*argv` is the first of those "strings". `**argv` is the first character of the first "string". A "string" being a character array in C.

Answer (score 0):

This is all because an array is also a pointer to the first element in the array in c.  `**argv` dereferences our pointer to pointer to char twice, giving us a char.  `*argv[0]` is basically saying 'dereference that address, and return the first element in the array described by the address we just got from dereferencing,' which happens to be the same thing.  `*argv` only dereferences once, so we still have a pointer to char, or a char array.  `*argv + 1` dereferences once, giving us the first character string, and then adds 1 to the address, giving us the address of the second element.  Because pointers are also arrays, we can say that this is the array `*argv` minus the first element.

Comment: An array is **not** a pointer. Arrays are arrays, and pointers are pointers.

Comment: Please revise. Arrays and pointers are different.

Comment: I beg to differ.  If you declare an array like this: `int a[];` it is exactly the same as saying this: `int* a;`.  Fundamentally, an array is just a pointer to a bunch of data arranged consecutively in memory.

Comment: How do you figure? `int a[];` won't compile since there's no array size. If you have `int c = 3;` you can assign it's address to a pointer such as `int *b = &c;`. If you try that with an array `int a[1]; a = &c;` you get `error: incompatible types` because you can't assign an array any address you want as you can a pointer. Because it's not a pointer. Arrays don't "point".

Comment: Then try compiling this: `int a[3] = {0,1,2}; int b = *a; int c = *(a+2); int* d = a; int e = d[1];`  You will find it compiles just fine.  I realize that you can't declare an array with no size, but if you declare one with a size, you can treat it as a pointer in every sense except assignment.  This is because the array is fixed in memory location, and thus the array actually has a type of `const int *`.  However, you can assign a random pointer to an array, and manipulate the array through the pointer just like the pointer is an array, because they are essentially the same thing.